# Form validation in Asgard CMS

Tags: php, laravel, asgardcms

I am working on a custom module in AsgardCMS and have discovered the Laravel form validation I know and love  does not work.  Instead, if I submit the form in violation of the rules, it does not throw an error, it just accepts it and carries on.

Is there some 3rd party validation at work that I'm not seeing?

Even just a link to some documentation would be much appreciated...docs for Asgard seem scarce.

```
$request->validate([
  'name' => 'required|max:60',
  'location_id' => 'required|integer',
  'comment' => 'required|min:10|max:500'
];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out after some digging.  In `Modules/Yourmodule/Http/Requests` folder you will find `Create###Request.php` and `Update###Request.php` that contain a rules() and translationRules() method where you can apply your validation rules.